# Computer Starts But monitor does not along with USB Keyboard/mouse

Tags: usb, display

Computer Starts But monitor does not along with USB Keyboard/mouse.

The computer is a   INSPIRON 546S bought from walmart in 2010.
monitor came with this setup.
I have tried hooking another monitor to the system with no luck.
It was working fine until earlier when i took out a faulty dvd drive and put a new one in. 
I have already reseated ram/video card unplugged all wires and reconnected.
I cannot figure out why my usb connections  or my monitor is not working. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know of the machine is POSTing? Does it give a little beep sound a few seconds after being turned on? Did it ever give such a beep?

Comment: It Wasn't doing it until about 20 minutes ago. 5 short beeps over and over. It wasnt doing it at first and doesnt do it everytime.

Comment: did you try booting it with new drive removed?

Comment: yes i tried booting it over and over with just the HDD connected and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your machine is not POSTing (Power On Self-Test). multiple short beeps means something key isn't working - 5 of them is a code for something.

I suspect your video card isn't fully inserted. Inspect it very carefully and make sure all the connectors on it are fully inserted.

If you have an integrated video card, that's a deeper problem and could mean either your CPU or RAM are in real trouble. If you're sure you've got that stuff properly inserted/connected, then the last thing I'd check is that your power supply is properly hooked up. If you're sure your motherboard is getting sufficient power and everything's inserted properly, than one of those key components is very likely not working properly and you'll need to go through a process of isolation and testing to find the problem.. Or just take the machine in and have someone else do the same thing for you.

Edit: [this page contains look up tables for various BIOS maker's beep codes](http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_beep_codes).

Comment: yes My computer is turning on when i press the power button but neither the onboard or other video card will   bring the monitor on. I have tried the monitor on a diff computer and it works fine.

Comment: also the usb isnt working, though the little LED on the Motherboard is ON. With the motherboard LED being on the Motherboard is fine correct? if so that would only leave the CPU or what correct?

Comment: From what you're describing, your computer isn't really getting far enough in to start up for the keyboard or mouse to be necessary. Can you please remove the video card you added and try operating just off of the onboard card?

Comment: Just tried taking out old video card and booting computer up with a different monitor/same monitor neither would come out of standby.

Comment: And you still get the beep code (5 beeps)? If you know who made your BIOS, you can try looking up what 5 beeps stands for here: http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_beep_codes

Comment: no i dont get the beep everytime i turn on the computer.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonably non-trivial hardware failure. Is the machine still within its warranty period?

Comment: no unfortuantly it isnt. Any ideas what you think it is?

Comment: I have also tried replacing the PSU with 2 other different PSU's and it still does the same thing.

Comment: It's likely your motherboard. Possibly your CPU. Unless you're extremely proficient with dealing with hardware failtures, you'll need to replace one of them (maybe both). I'd bet on the motherboard before the CPU.

Comment: Ok will Do, thanks for the help. will send it off when i can.

Comment: Good luck - may as well try Kyle's suggestion while you're at it - disconnecting various things like hard drives and your new CD drive. But I'd be pretty freaked if a peripheral like that could cause this kind of fundamental problem. Still, easy to try anyway. Though sounds like your hardware is flaking out regardless.